# Retain entry field in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a pop up text entry field as part of my GUI asking for two entries #1 Filepath #2 Item (these reference an excel sheet)

The filepath will rarely change but the ability to change it when needed is still required

Is it possible to retain the filepath in the entry field so it dosnt require typing each and every time? i.e after closing and re opening the entry field still contains `C:\*\*\*\*\*\somthing.xlsx`.

```
master = Tk()
master.title("Entry Field")
Label(master, text="Filepath: ").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Item Number: ").grid(row=1)
e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

def entry_field():
    print("Filepath: %s" % (e1.get()))
    print("Item No: %s" % (e2.get()))

    Button(master, 
           text = 'Accept', 
           command = entry_field).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tk.Entry widget will keep the values until you reset them to a new value (you can see this when pressing the `Accept` button several times without modifying the `Entry`; you therefore do not need to do anything special.

You could pro-actively insert a default value in your entry:

```
import tkinter as tk

def entry_field():
    print("Filepath: %s" % (e1.get()))
    print("Item No: %s" % (e2.get()))

master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Entry Field")
tk.Label(master, text="Filepath: ").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master, text="Item Number: ").grid(row=1)


e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)
e1.insert(0, 'C:*****\somthing.xlsx')    # <-- this string will be inserted in the Entry by default

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

tk.Button(master, text = 'Accept', command = entry_field).grid(row=3, column=1,
                                sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
master.mainloop()
```

This is how the entry appears by default now:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to keep the actual text itself in the entry field? the value is retained but i want the text to also remain there until deleted and re-entered. If not possible a work round would be to display current filepath above the entry field

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by 'keep the actual text in the entry field'? How does that differ from the text entered remaining in the entry field?

Comment: So the sequence is in parent GUI press button -> Entry field pops up -> enter data -> click accept button -> close window

When i press the button to open this entry field again while the filepath is still stored as a value its not visable in the entry field the entry field is empty

Comment: I see... yes, you can: keep the text entered in a variable that you can insert in the entry field each time you re-create it via your pop-up. `e1.insert(0, last_entered_text)`

Comment: whoops, I left some garbage... I cleaned it up, you can try again.

Comment: I have this working now, when i close the pop up and reopen it retains the text. However when i close the (main) Parent window and reopen the field is empty again. I suspect i need to make it a Global Variable is this correct?

Comment: Yes, a global variable, or a class to encapsulate the data, whichever you are most comfortable with. Why don't you try and see if you can do it? Ask a new question if you are having difficulties; feel free to tag me in a comment under your new question (use @Reblochon), to draw my attention to it, I'll be happy to help you.