# How to retain the value of an entry field acquired in a popup toplevel window in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I cannot get my code to pass the pop up text entry to a global variable i am also attempting to set this global variable as the default text in the entry field in all future instances.

Pop up -> Enter Filepath -> accept&close -> Re-open shows last filepath present as default -> if changed new filepath entry becomes default in future.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

master = tk.Tk()

Var1 = StringVar()
Filepath_Var = None

def A_Connect():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Entry Field")

    def entry_field():
        global Filepath_Var
        Filepath_Var = Var1.get()

    tk.Label(root, text="filepath: ").grid(row=0)
    e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=Var1)

    tk.Label(root, text="Item Number: ").grid(row=1)
    e2 = tk.Entry(root)
    #e1.insert(0, r"C:\Users\zxy\ghj\iugf\Bea\something.xlsx")
    e1.insert(0, Var1.get())

    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    Button(root, text = 'Accept', command = entry_field).grid(row=3, column=1,
                                    sticky=W, pady=4)
    root.mainloop()

note = ttk.Notebook(master)

tab1 = tk.Frame(note)

canvas7 = Canvas(tab1, width=520, height=350)
canvas7.pack()

A_Button = tk.Button(tab1, text="A",
                       width=12, height=3,command=A_Connect, anchor = 'w')
A_Button_Window = canvas7.create_window(20, 120, anchor = 'sw',
                                         window = A_Button)

note.add(tab1, text = "  Main    ")

note.pack()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Reblochon had numerous unsuccessful attempts

Comment: It's probably because you're calling `Tk()` twice (for `master` and `root`)—something that will generally mess things up. If you need another window, create it with [`Toplevel`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html) instead. However in this case you probably just need to eliminate one of them.

Comment: `from tkinter import *` defeats the purpose of `import tkinter as tk`. Use either one or the other or you'll only confuse yourself.

Comment: Good on you for trying @MattyTomlinson; I provided a working skeleton that you can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684658/retain-entry-field-in-python-tkinter), I encapsulated an example of the (bare bones) desired behavior in two classes:

The main App consists of a button that launches an entry popup; upon filling the fields and accepting, the value in the entry is provided to the App, and the popup closed.

The value entered is stored by the App, and used to populate the entry field of the entry fields in successive popups.

You will probably want to add confirmations and verifications before changing the defaults, and closing the popup, but here, you have the basic skeleton to attach this to.

```
import tkinter as tk


class PopUpEntry(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, default_value=None):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(self.master)
        if default_value is None:
            self.default_entry = 'C:*****\somthing.xlsx'
        else:
            self.default_entry = default_value
        self.title("Entry Field")
        tk.Label(self, text="Filepath: ").pack()
        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.e1.insert(0, self.default_entry)
        self.e1.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text = 'Accept', command=self.entry_field).pack()

    def entry_field(self):
        self.default_entry = self.e1.get()
        self.master.provide_entry_value(self.default_entry)
        self.destroy()


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pop_entry = tk.Button(self, text='launch entry', command=self.launch_entry)
        self.pop_entry.pack()
        self.default_entry_value = None
        self.mainloop()

    def launch_entry(self):
        PopUpEntry(self, self.default_entry_value)

    def provide_entry_value(self, value):
        self.default_entry_value = value
        print(self.default_entry_value)

App()
```

Comment: thanks again for the help iv had a play around with this and incorporated it. 

Taking this further how would i go about retaining the value after the program closes? at present the filepath reverts to default upon launch and dosnt overwrite it with the new filepath entered

Comment: The way i was intending on addressing this was to have a text file filepath_variable.txt that python read/write the variable (filepath) from/to but was wondering if there was a better solution.